# Webサーバーには、セッションデータファイルを格納するパスへの書き込みアクセス権がありません。

Tags: php, fuelphp

URLにアクセスすると、

エラー

```
Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]:
The webserver doesn't have write access to the path to store the session data files.

COREPATH/classes/session/file.php @ line 341
throw new \FuelException('The webserver doesn\'t have write access to the path to store the session data files.');
```

となりました。

$ cat /etc/php.ini | grep session.save_path

```
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*


$ cat /etc/php.ini | grep session.save_path 
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;session.save_path = "/tmp"
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
```

試したこと
(1)php.iniの設定

```
;session.save_path = "/tmp" → session.save_path = "/tmp"
```

(2)アクセス権の設定

```
session.save_path="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"の
アクセス権を777に設定
```

この場合のエラーの原因は何が考えられるのかご教示下さいませんか。

お手数おかけしますが、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いします。

環境
macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
session.save_path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/

Comment: `php.ini`で設定したディレクトリとアクセス権をいじっているディレクトリとが一致していないように見えます。何処にセッションを保存するつもりなのかをはっきりさせてから、もう一度設定項目をチェックしてみてください。

Comment: session.save_path = "/tmp"を ;session.save_path = "/tmp"にし、session.save_path="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"に設定し、中を覗くとsessから始まるファイルが4つあります。ちゃんとセッションが保存されているのかなと思います。しかし、セッションファイルの保存が出来ていて、アクセス権も777になっているのにまだ同じエラーが出るのは何が原因だと考えられますか？

Comment: @blockchain2018 どういうことです？2つ`session.save_path`書いていると言うことですか？それとも`"/tmp"`で`"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"`に保存されていると考えているということですか？

Comment: @Myaku 2つsession.save_pathに書いていません。"/tmpで"/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"に保存されているのではなく、session.save_pathを/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/にして、/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/にsessファイルが保存されています。

Comment: パソコンの中にあるいくつかのtempフォルダを確認しましたが、sessファイルが入っているのはこの/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/だけでした

Comment: @blockchain2018 試したこと`(1)php.iniの設定`では、`(2)`の`session.save_path="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"`にはならないとおもいますが…、また実行環境も記載してください。Centosなどの`Linux`ですか？`Mac`ですか？また、追加情報は質問文を編集して追記してください。

Comment: session.save_path="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/"は自分で設定しました。macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6です。ちなみに先ほどエラーページが出なくなりました。エラーが解消された理由は自身でもまだわかってません。

Comment: `phpinfo`で最終的に反映されている設定が確認できるので、この方法で`session.save_path`の値がどうなっているのかを確認の上、質問文に追記してみてください - [参考ページ](https://webkaru.net/php/function-phpinfo/)

Comment: phpinfoで確認するとsession.save_path /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/でした。追記しておきます。@cubick

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/143393

Comment: @cubick 本日からマルチポストをしない事を誓います。

Comment: @blockchain2018 マルチポストをするなという意味で展開したのでは無いと思います。[マルチポストとはなんですか-何か問題があるのでしょうか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418)をご覧ください。マルチポストしている旨は明記すべきで、またマルチポスト先で解決した場合は全ての投稿先で回答を共有しメンテすれば問題はありません。